# How do I use common templates with $stateProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm quite new to AngularJS so please bear with me.

I have an app and I want to have common templates in it, for example a toolbar.
I've seen working examples in similar (but not exact) cases :

- Declare a state parent with "abstract" set to true and declare the common templates
- Declare a state child with "parent" set to true or using the dot notation and declare a template specific to the page

But those examples always use the index.html as the container for the common elements.

In my case, those common elements only appear in a certain section of the site.

Here's an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MMAoBXy9btGSqni2dRqL?p=preview

I could move the toolbar declaration to the "hello" state but then the common template would have to be linked to each state, like so:

```
$stateProvider

    .state('listmedias', {
        url : '',
        abstract : 'true',
        views : {
            'main@' : {
                templateUrl : 'hello.tpl.html'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('hello', {
        url : '/hello',
        parent : 'listmedias',
        views : {
            'toolbar' : {
                templateUrl : 'commonelement.tpl.html'
            }
            'container': {
                templateUrl : 'container.tpl.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

What can I do to have some sub section of the site use some common elements?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out,

```
.state('listmedias', {
  url : '',
  abstract : 'true',
  views : {
    'main@' : {
      templateUrl : 'hello.tpl.html'
    },
    'toolbar@listmedias' : {
      templateUrl : 'commonelement.tpl.html'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

For anyone wondering why, I looked up the relevant documentation : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views (last piece of code on the page)